# Send content of a canvas more efficiently

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, canvas

I want to send a canvas  with transparency. Unfortunetly the rendered canvas as PNG is very big. Is there anything I can do to make it smaller for the transferring?

```
var canvasPNG = canvas.toDataURL();  //sending it to the server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really if you send it as a png with alpha channel.

What you *could* do is to send the image as two jpeg images: one image containing the rgb, and another greyscale image representing the alpha channel, and then create a png on the server from those.

Comment: But getting out the colors of the channels would mean to filter each pixel, that also takes long, or is there custom way?

Comment: You can create the greyscale image without having to iterate over the pixels. Create a new canvas and fill it with white. Then draw the image you want to transfer using globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in" into it. Then take this image which only contains white and transpareny and draw it to a black canvas. You now have an image which is greyscale, where black represents totally transparent and white represents opaque.

Comment: but then I need to turn on the server any pixel that is black into transparent, or on the client-side when the server has sent the mask and the img data to another client

Comment: yes, but server-side you usually have a lot more options if you have control over it. Many image manipulation libraries support copying channel data as one operation. So you basically copy one of the channels in the greyscale image (doesn't matter which channel since it's greyscale) to the alpha channel in the color image.

Comment: Ok, it looks like you're sending the image between javascript clients using node.js. In that case it sounds like it's better to instead of sending a greyscale image as jpg just send the white image with transparency as a png (since it only contains white color with different alpha values, it should compress well as png, assuming there are larges areas that are completely transparent or large areas completely opaque) and use that as a mask on the color jpg on the client side using globalCompositeOperation.